# LocalStorage is dismissed after app restarting. Maui&Blazor

Tags: blazor, webassembly, maui, webview2

I develop an app with MAUI&Blazor on the windows platform. For storing the page states, the states are persisted in the [local storage](https://github.com/Blazored/LocalStorage). But with every app restarting, those states are missing.

The Maui reuses the system browser, which should have some settings for itself.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> But with every app restarting, those states are missing.

In maui, you can use [IPreferences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/preferences?tabs=android) interface  or  [ISecureStorage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/secure-storage?tabs=android)  interface to save page states, and retrieve these values after restarting the app.
This interface helps store app preferences in a key/value store.

The default implementation of the `IPreferences` interface is available through the `Preferences.Default` property. Both the `IPreferences` interface and Preferences class are contained in the `Microsoft.Maui.Storage` namespace.

You can save your page status and resume it on method `OnAppearing`.

Please refer to the following code:

**Set preferences**

Preferences are set by calling the Preferences.Set method, providing the key and value:

```
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
        // Set a string value:
        Preferences.Default.Set("first_name", "John");

        // Set an numerical value:
        Preferences.Default.Set("age", 28);
    }
```

**Get preferences**

To retrieve a value from preferences, you pass the key of the preference, followed by the default value when the key doesn't exist:

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();

    string firstName = Preferences.Default.Get("first_name", "Unknown");
    int age = Preferences.Default.Get("age", -1);

    mNameLabel.Text = "Name : " + firstName;

    mAgeLabel.Text = "Age : " + age;
}
```

**Note:**

For more Preferences, you can check: [Preferences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/preferences?tabs=android).

For more about Secure storage, you can check: [Secure storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/secure-storage?tabs=android)

Comment: Hi @Echo, if my reply is useful for this problem, could you please mark the reply as answered so that it will help others who have similar problems? Thanks in advance. :)